# Debian squeeze: how to disable synaptics touchpad

Tags: debian, touchpad

I just did a huge full-upgrade (been a while since the last so a lot of stuff changed) and also upgraded to kernel 2.6.30.
After this I'm having some annoyances with the touchpad: the worst thing is that I can't turn it of anymore. I used to do it with a simple

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

then with `xinput` as per [this message](http://Linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Fedora/2009-07/msg03502.HTML), but then I had to tweak `psmouse` module as suggested in the [SynapticsTouchpad Debian Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad) because the tap-click wasn't working anymore. After that I can't disable that stupid device by no means: no synclient, no xinput, no gsynaptics.

I also dislike the new pointer speed and can't tweak that either, but that's a minor annoyance since I use the touchpad only when I can't use the mouse (and the reason I want to turn it off is that I keep hitting it with my thumbs while typing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In lieu of fully disabling the touchpad, you could try [touchfreeze](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/touchfreeze-tray-icon-that-disables-your-touchpad-while-typing.html), which should disable the touchpad only while you are typing. I've never tried it on Debian, but I have used it on Ubuntu it worked fairly well.

Answer (score 3):

Oh well, my mistake was trying to be too specific:

```
# modprobe -r psmouse
```

took care of the damn thing for good.

Comment: +1 for a non "apt-get that and your problem will be solved" solution.